# Finding the cumulative distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

How can I find the cumulative distribution function for the following prob density.
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{if } 0<x<1 \\ 2-x & \text{if } 1 \leq x <2 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
This is what I did

**First I did 0 for $x\le0$**

**if $0<x<1$** then

$\int_0^xf(y)\,dy=\int_0^xy\,dy=\frac{x^2}{2}$

**if $1\le x <2$**

$\int_0^1y\,dy+\int_1^x(2-y)\,dy=\frac{1}{2}+\big(2x-\frac{x^2}{2}-({2}-\frac{1}{2})\big)$

**if $x\ge2$ then 1**

But would my cumulative distribution be correct?

Comment: @drhab the only difference is that your answer in the other question for if $1<\le x<2$ is differnet from mine. I think you used t as a variable and I used y.

Comment: Well @Fernando, that is relieving. Your answer is correct. Just like mine ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cumulative distribution is defined in a piecewise way, just as you have written. So when $0\leq x<1$, $F(x)=x^2/2$.